# Java : What to add for Class Type arguments?

Tags: java, class, types, arguments

I am working on simulating wireless sensor network. I have to create a nodes in the simulation.

Functions to create nodes is defined in class `Simulator`. Here `Simulator` and `RadioModel` are two user defined classes.

For creating a node , I have a pre-defined function i.e. `createNode()` defined within `Simulator` class. It has following syntax:

```
Node createNode(Class nodeClass, RadioModel radioModel, int nodeId, 
                double x, double y, double z)
```

Here I am fine with `RadioModel` parameter and all other arguments except `"Class nodeClass"` are working fine. What to substitute for this argument i.e. `nodeclass`?

Any help will be of great use....

---

Yes dacwe, as you said Node class is extended by Mica2Node class which I am instantiating. And I have passed the argument as
 `sim1.createNode(Mica2Node.class, g, nodeId,x,y,z);`

Here sim1 is an object of class Simulator and g is an object of class RadioModel. Beacause createNode is not a static method, I called it through object. But I am facing three other warnings: from other class i,e. Application.java

```
public Application(Node node){
    this.node = node;
    node.addApplication(this);
}
```

here it is showing error in addApplication(this) method. This method is defined in Node.java as below:

```
public void addApplication(Application app){
    app.nextApplication = firstApplication;
    firstApplication = app; }
```

And the error is as below:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: ()void
    at net.tinyos.prowler.Application.(Application.java:31)
    at net.tinyos.prowler.TestBroadcastNode$BroadcastApplication.(TestBroadcastNode.java:36)
    at net.tinyos.prowler.TestBroadcastNode.main(TestBroadcastNode.java:118)

Please help me out......

Comment: If you have multiple classes of nodes, why not have them all inherit from an abstract class with method `createNode(RadioModel radioModel, int nodeId, double x, double y, double z)`, then call `Node n = new SpecificNode(radModel, nodeId, x, y, z);`?

Comment: Please simply edit your question if you want to provide additional details. Answers are reserved strictly for solutions that solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public <T extends Node> T createNode(Class<T> clazz, RadioModel radioModel, 
            int nodeId, double x, double y, double z);
```

Which can be used like

```
RadioModel radioModel = ... 
MyNode node = createNode(MyNode.class, radioModel, 1, 2, 3);
```

Another approach might be to create a factory which encapsulates the creation of all node types, e.g.,

```
public interface NodeFactory {
     public MyNode createMyNode(..);
     public YourNode createYourNode(..);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is (proably) whay kind of class the `createNode` method should create.

You have some "node classes" that extend `Node` (in the example below `BigNode` and `SomeOtherNode`). So you use the class information to create one of those.

The calling part:

```
 Node created = Simulator.createNode(BigNode.class, radioModel, nodeId, x, y, z);
```

The implementation of `createNode`:

```
Node createNode(Class nodeClass, RadioModel radioModel, int nodeId, 
                double x, double y, double z) {

    if (nodeClass.equals(BigNode.class))
        return new BigNode(radioModel, nodeId, x, y, z);

    if (nodeClass.equals(SomeOtherNode.class)) {
        return new SomeOtherNode(.....);

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not create node of type " + 
                                       nodeClass);
}
```

Comment: I think that's what he's asking for, but adjusting the signature or utilizing a factory, or even the principle of double dispatch, you can get away without any `instanceof` statements.

Comment: Ah, now that you mention it, it should be `equals`. Updated!

Comment: Yes dacwe, as you said Node class is extended by Mica2Node class which I am instantiating. And I have passed the argument as sim1.createNode(Mica2Node.class, g, nodeId,x,y,z);  Here sim1 is an object of class Simulator and g is an object of class RadioModel. Beacause createNode is not a static method, I called it through object. But I am facing three other warnings: from other class i,e. Application.java     public Application(Node node){
  this.node = node;
  node.addApplication(this);
 }